# Why did Stingray have a number 3 on its fin?

Tags: gerry-anderson

[image: Stingray]

[Image from teletronic](https://web.archive.org/web/20160324020306/http://www.teletronic.co.uk/gerry_anderson_2.htm)

Gerry Anderson's Stingray has the number 3 on its fin. But why is this? The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_%28TV_series%29) fails here because it gives *three different reasons*!

1. Under [Story and characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_%28TV_series%29#Story_and_characters), the reason is (apparently) because, *"Stingray is launched from the base's "Pen 3"* (confirmed on the [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Stingray_%28TV_series%29#The_Number_Three.3F)).
2. Under [Voice actors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_%28TV_series%29#Voice_actors), this sentence is inexplicably added, *"According to the audio adventure 'Journey to Marineville' the 3 on Stingray's fins indicates she is Stingray Mark III ..."*
3. Finally, under ["Stingray Class"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stingray_%28TV_series%29#.22Stingray_Class.22), it says, *"According to the Stingray comic strip in the weekly Countdown comic there was more than one Stingray class submarine in the Marineville fleet. They had names like Spearfish, Barracuda, Moray and Thornback and were identified by different numbers on their fins suggesting that the '3' on Stingray's fins did not indicate she was Stingray Mark III after all."*

Three different reasons on the same page! So what is the real reason?

Comment: Interesting. Has it always had 3 on it's fins? It's unusual to denote Mk III so prominently like over an identification number etc, I'd probably go more with answer 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since I was a young boy I had The Stingray Mini Album from Century 21 productions, they released a number of mini stories on a single sized vinyl LP. On the LP I had a story which was entitled *'A trip to Marineville'* in which a young boy named Johnny takes a tour of Marineville with Troy Tempest.

Near the end of side 2, Troy shows Johnny the Stingray. Johnny asks

> 'Why does she have an number 3 on her fin?'

and receives the reply from Troy

> Well, that's because she's the third one. **There were two other stingrays before this one. Each was taken out of commission when the new one was designed, so this is Stingray Mark III**

Answer (score 3):

I can't give a definitive canon answer but I can tell you what would influence that number being placed on the fin.

WW2 RAF aircraft had a '[Fin Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Air_Force_roundels#Fin_flash)' featuring a serial number. [Gerry Anderson's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerry_Anderson) older brother was an RAF pilot and later he himself served in the RAF so he should have been very familiar with the fin flash and other plane markings which would have strongly influenced the markings on his fictional machines.

In [Thunderbirds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_%28TV_series%29) each [machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbirds_machines) has a number on it's fin indicating it's order of build, use, or importance. Even though Stingray was made before Thunderbirds, the the thinking for numbering the machines is probably similar to that employed for Thunderbirds. Thus it is most likely that the third point in the question is the reason why the number 3 is used, as this is the third vehicle in use which is also housed in a matching numbered pen. If there was only a single submarine there would be no number on the fin.

Given these influences we can assume that there is a number on the fin because the Marineville fleet uses it to identify their ships in a similar manner to the RAF and it is the number three because Stingray is the third ship.

Comment: I doubt Thunderbirds follows the same numbering logic as in other shows or real-life inspirations. Each Thunderbird was a one-off vehicle serving a specific role (quick response/co-ordination, equipment transport, surface/orbit shuttle, undersea operations, global monitoring. Numbers facilitated easy reference in communications. I may be wrong, but wasn't one of the Thunderbirds destroyed in one episode, and upon replacement, kept its original "tail" number?

Answer (score 1):

The Gerry Anderson *Stingray Special* magazine 1983 has a story - Deep Sea Doom - which includes vessel 4, the Spearfish. Depending on how you read the story a guy with a grudge had already disposed of 2 and after Spearfish he then destroyed Barracuda and just needed to destroy Stingray. If that reading is correct there should be at least 5 pens. The grudge was against 5 officers not their subs, in the case of Stingray he wanted to kill Phones. The vessels were destroyed by model stingrays packed with explosive. Barracuda may have been vessel 2 as the model stingray used to attack Barracuda had a number 2 on it. The same story titled this time Model Mission is in issue 22 of Countdown of July 17 1971.

Another quote I have found is

> According to the Stingray comic strip in the weekly Countdown comic there was more than one Stingray class submarine in the Marineville fleet. They had names like Spearfish, Barracuda, Moray and Thornback and were identified by different numbers on their fins suggesting that the '3' on Stingray's fins did not indicate she was Stingray Mark III after all.

I checked Countdown the only reference to other stingray vessels was the 1971 story which is identical to the one used in the 1983 special - apart from its name.  Spearfish and Barracuda are shown while Thornback and Moray are referred to in the text as making rendezvous with Stingray.  Only Spearfish is shown in such a way that its number -4- can be seen. I can not make out the number on Barracuda.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you supply a source for your quote?

Comment: The quote comes from https://culture.fandom.com/wiki/Stingray_(TV_series) it does not make reference to the issue of the comic as far as I can see.  There is a Deviant art user ArthurTwosheds who has done images of 16 named Stingray class. He mentions TV21 as a source for some of his work but not specifically for the Stingray images. He does not have a number 2 as he said that was a conventional submarine used to test systems and gives Barracuda number 5.

Answer (score 0):

Better as a comment but too long: Chris Thompson, writing for "[Gerry Anderson News](https://www.gerryanderson.co.uk/the-w-a-s-p-fleet/?utm_source=Gerry%20Anderson%20Newsletter&utm_campaign=10ff18db74-EMAIL_CAMPAIGN_2016_11_05&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_3f6ad8f11c-10ff18db74-120774857&mc_cid=10ff18db74&mc_eid=305c15af91)" notes that no backstory was ever written for Stingray, and all we have is "a hint that Commander Shore may have captained her at one point" (any ideas of which story this is from?), but no information about the number '3' on the side. He speculated what this meant: "Is that Stingray is third in her class? The third ship in the WASP fleet? Or simply the third hero craft designed by Bob Bell?"

[Bob Bell](https://gerryanderson.fandom.com/wiki/Bob_Bell) was the Art Director on several Anderson shows and seems to be credited by Thompson with designing Stingray (though this isn't mentioned either on the Gerry Anderson site or his Wikipedia listing).

Thompson, being a designer himself, goes on to explore two other classes of ship before Stingray, the first being Thresher and second being called Swordfish.